# only one header between two Activities

Tags: android, android-activity

how can i switch between two activities wich have the same header, for example an image. what i mean is, that their is an animation between the two activities, so the image is animated too. But i want, that only the body is animate and the image looks like freeze at the top. maybe i had to solve the probleme in another way because i have an activity with a listview inside an for example an imageview at the top. Now after i click on an item in the listview i want to refill the listview with an animation like move out - move in. i do so with two activities, but in this case, the imageview at the top is animated too. how can solve this problem. Do i need two activities or one. if(activity == one) { How can i animate the refill of the listview }

I hope you understand what i mean.

Thx for the answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But i want, that only the body is animate and the image looks like freeze at the top.

That is not possible with multiple activities.

> How can i animate the refill of the listview

Have two `ListView` widgets and animate one out and the other in, putting your new data into the one that is animating in. You could accomplish this with a `ViewFlipper` as the container, or apply the animations directly to the widgets.

Or, switch to fragments (Android 3.0 and the Android Compatibility Library) and use `FragmentTransactions` to animate a pair of `ListFragments`.

Comment: okay i will test it. another question in this case is: can i animate back to the listview i saw before by pressing the back stack...like between to activities?

Comment: @user683813: If you go with `FragmentTransaction`, it can manage the BACK state for you. If you go with `ViewFlipper`, you will have to handle the BACK button yourself.

Comment: Okay...so how can i catch the event of the back stack?! So that anything should happen, if the backstack is pressed in this activity to flip back in the view flipper?

Comment: @user683813: Override `onBackPressed()` in your activity. If you need to support Android 1.x devices, you will also need to override `onKeyDown()` in your activity and watch for the BACK button `KeyEvent`.

Comment: Just a correction: if you need to support Android 1.x, you need to *instead* override `onKeyDown()`. Overriding a nonexistent method will fail the classloader verification, so you must abandon `onBackPressed()` entirely. [Android 2.0 release notes](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.0.html#api-changes) have an example code that deals with the change in keyDown/keyUp handling.

Comment: @mernen: The "a nonexistent method will fail the classloader verification" issue would, at most, come if you use the `@Override` annotation, and I'm not even sure that will cause a problem. Otherwise, it would simply be an ignored method.

Comment: I can't test right now, but thinking about it, the issue is most probably that I was invoking `super.onBackPressed()`. So, if you want to fall back to the default behavior, you should call `finish()` directly.

Comment: @mernen: Ah, yes, that will be a problem. Didn't think of that -- my apologies.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it only inside one activity.
You should implement Tweened Animation for list view and start it any time it was updated